# Log compaction to keep exactly one message per key

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to create a topic which contains unique keys along with their corresponding most recent values. So when a message with an existing key is inserted to the topic, the old message is removed.

To do so, I have configured the following parameters in `server.properties` file:

```
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleanup.policy=compact

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.minutes=3

log.retention.bytes=10737418

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000

# The maximum time before a new log segment is rolled out (in milliseconds).
# If not set, the value in log.roll.hours is used
log.roll.ms=600000
```

So that compaction should take place every 3 minutes. In order to test compaction policy I have created a topic `retention_test`

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic retention_test --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

and using the console consumer, `kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic retention_test --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=:` I have produced the following messages:

```
>1:first
>2:second
>3:third
```

where the console consumer `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic retention_test --from-beginning` consumes them successfully;

```
first
second
third
```

Now when I try to insert a message with a key which has already been added, the older message doesn't seem to be ignored and remains in the topic:

In the producer's side:

```
>1:updatedFirst
```

Note that in order to test the behavior, I have restarted the consumer multiple times, long after the retention period of 3 minutes has passed. The output is

```
first
second
third
updatedFirst
```

The desired output should have been

```
second
third
updatedFirst
```

since `first` and `updatedFirst` have the same key.

According to the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction):

> Log compaction gives us a more granular retention mechanism so that we are guaranteed to retain **at least the last update** for each
>   primary key

Is it possible to keep **exactly** one message (the most recent one) per key instead of at least one message (including the most recent one)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say it's not generally possible. Kafka stores messages in segments for each partition of each topic. Each segment is a file and they are only ever appended to (or deleted as a whole). Compaction only works by re-writing the existing segment files skipping the messages for which there are later messages with the same key. However, the head segment (the one to which currently new messages are being appended) is not compacted (until a new segment is created which becomes the head segment).

The 3 minutes you configured via `log.retention` config is not in play when `log.cleanup.policy=compact`, it's only effective when `log.cleanup.policy=delete`

Why is having exactly one message for a given key important? Perhaps an alternative approach can be suggested if you provide more info about your use case.

Comment: I see! So two messages with the same key might both belong to the head segment and therefore will bot be compacted. Thanks for the explanation.